# Foundation 5 - Joyride not working

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

I'm struggling to get Joyride to work.  I have entered the code as described on the Zurb documentation but it simply won't run.  I need some advice on what I might be doing wrong.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <ul>
      <li><h2 id="firstStop" class="panel">First</h2></li>
      <li><h2 id="secondStop" class="panel">Second</h2></li   

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

At the foot of the page I have

```
<!-- At the bottom of your page but inside of the body tag --> 
    <ol class="joyride-list" data-joyride>
      <li data-id="firstStop" data-text="Next">
        <p>Test</p>
      </li>
      <li data-id="secondStop" data-text="Next">
        <p>Test</p>
      </li>
      <li data-button="End">
        <p>Test</p>
      </li>  
    </ol>
```

And foundation initialized as

```
$(document).foundation('joyride', 'start');
```

However nothing happens when I load the page. I'm a touch confused now. Can anyone hel?

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer to my own question but I had to creep into the Foundation 5 demonstration code behind to find it.  The initialisation of joyride which isn't actually even document needs to be as follow:

```
$(document).foundation().foundation('joyride', 'start');
```

Why Zurb don't mention this is a total mystery.